# Adding JLabels to a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jlist

So far, I've tried simply going through my labels and adding each one to the list's list model with:

```
listModel.addElement(label);
```

So this works, but it simply gives a string representation of the label rather than the actual label.

Basically, is it possible to have a JList of JLabels? If not, then what's a good way to have a scrollable list of JLabels that I can update?

Comment: Looks like there is something fundamentally wrong in what you are trying to do. The `JList` already presents you like a list of labels ( non editable items that you can change via code). You may want to update your question with more detail. And, the [DefaultListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) already extends JLabel

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'm trying to do something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/NTcwm.png), though, and it seemed like it would be appropriate to use JLabels.

Comment: may be just use HTML in your labels

Comment: Yeah, that's what I currently have. I'm able to generate the labels fine, but I'm not really sure where to put them afterwards to achieve the desired effect. A JList seemed appropriate in thought, but it doesn't seem to work well in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JList`, `JTable`, `JComboBox's popup` return by default `JLabel / JComponent` from the `Renderer`, then there is no reason to put those `JComponents` types to the `JList` (in this case)

```
but it simply gives a string representation of the label rather than the actual label
```

- please read how [Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) to works, [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table-Renderer-Editor.htm) and [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html),
- concept of `Renderers` is similair for `JList`, `JTable`, `JComboBox's popup`

Comment: So in that case, where would it be appropriate to put JLabels if I wished to scroll through them and be able to select one? A JScrollPane?

Comment: right, hmmm this one could be interesting, please [read this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9887616/714968)

Answer (score 1):

There is (almost) never a need to put a `JComponent` in the model side of a Swing component (`JList`, `JTree`, `JTable`, ... ). In your `ListModel` you put the `Object`s you want to visualize in a `JList`, and you let the renderer take care of the representation.

So if you want to represent each `Object` as a special label you create that label in your renderer.

See the [Swing list tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information. This tutorial does not contain a custom renderer, but instead refers you to the [custom renderer section of the combobox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer), which is very similar